# Python 3.6 openurl behaviour is different in windows OS

Tags: python, windows, decode, urlopen

I'm a beginner in python language

i'm trying to use **urlopen** by **with** statement to get file content and print all the words of this file.

this is the example which i follow:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
with urlopen('http://sixty-north.com/c/t.txt') as story:
    story_words = []
    for line in story:
        line_words = line.decode('utf-8').split()
        for word in line_words:
            story_words.append(word)

print(story_words)
```

The code is working fine in the [pyfiddle](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/cd2e439a-b1da-4499-be40-711c3f56944a/?m=Saved%20fiddle) website, but not work in my local machine.

The result should be like this:

> ['It', 'was', 'the', 'best', 'of', 'times', 'it', 'was', 'the', 'worst', 'of', 'times', 'it', 'was', 'the', 'age', 'of', 'wisdom', 'it', 'was', 'the', 'age', 'of', 'foolishness', 'it', 'was', 'the', 'epoch', 'of', 'belief', 'it', 'was', 'the', 'epoch', 'of', 'incredulity', 'it', 'was', 'the', 'season', 'of', 'Light', 'it', 'was', 'the', 'season', 'of', 'Darkness', 'it', 'was', 'the', 'spring', 'of', 'hope', 'it', 'was', 'the', 'winter', 'of', 'despair', 'we', 'had', 'everything', 'before', 'us', 'we', 'had', 'nothing', 'before', 'us', 'we', 'were', 'all', 'going', 'direct', 'to', 'Heaven', 'we', 'were', 'all', 'going', 'direct', 'the', 'other', 'way', 'in', 'short', 'the', 'period', 'was', 'so', 'far', 'like', 'the', 'present', 'period', 'that', 'some', 'of', 'its', 'noisiest', 'authorities', 'insisted', 'on', 'its', 'being', 'received', 'for', 'good', 'or', 'for', 'evil', 'in', 'the', 'superlative', 'degree', 'of', 'comparison', 'only']

i'm using windows 10 with python Version 3.6

this is the error that shown to me when i try to print the words locally:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 4, in 
>       line_words = line.decode('utf-8').split()
>   UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte

I printed also the words without **decoding** to see how it come in both (pyfiddle and local):

**In pyfiddle**:

> [b'It', b'was', b'the', b'best', b'of', b'times', b'it', b'was', b'the', b'worst', b'of', b'times', b'it', b'was', b'the', b'age', b'of', b'wisdom', b'it', b'was', b'the', b'age', b'of', b'foolishness', b'it', b'was', b'the', b'epoch', b'of', b'belief', b'it', b'was', b'the', b'epoch', b'of', b'incredulity', b'it', b'was', b'the', b'season', b'of', b'Light', b'it', b'was', b'the', b'season', b'of', b'Darkness', b'it', b'was', b'the', b'spring', b'of', b'hope', b'it', b'was', b'the', b'winter', b'of', b'despair', b'we', b'had', b'everything', b'before', b'us', b'we', b'had', b'nothing', b'before', b'us', b'we', b'were', b'all', b'going', b'direct', b'to', b'Heaven', b'we', b'were', b'all', b'going', b'direct', b'the', b'other', b'way', b'in', b'short', b'the', b'period', b'was', b'so', b'far', b'like', b'the', b'present', b'period', b'that', b'some', b'of', b'its', b'noisiest', b'authorities', b'insisted', b'on', b'its', b'being', b'received', b'for', b'good', b'or', b'for', b'evil', b'in', b'the', b'superlative', b'degree', b'of', b'comparison', b'only']

**Local**:

> [b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03}\x91Qn\x840', b'D\xff\xf7\x14>L?Z\xa9\x97\x08d', b"\xd6\x86\x18\xd9\x06\xb4\xb7\xaf\xb3\xabU\xbb\x15\xed\x17\xc1o\xec\x8c'\x1fNG2\xf2\x02\x1a`N2\x91\xf3\x02\xbb\xf078D\xff", b'iF\xaf\x1flY\x96\x130\x89T\xb6\xd2`/mXe,\x9d\x0f\xa8\x8c\xe9\x14q\x1b\x15y\xab\xec\xb7\x9f\xdc\x90LZ\x17|\xf2\\xfc\x1c\xbd%\xbd\xfe\xbe\xd3V\xe56wZd\xc5\xcbz\xdc\x1c\xdaI\x86\xad\x89\xf5r\x80J\xca\x84\x1dz\xf3\xd2\xdb\x06L\xa2\xa0\xcd\x9e\xac\xc9', b'8\x10\xc7T+\xcd\xd2Yf\xc5\xe8\xe4B\xefH;\xda?\x92\xb0\x11\x03\xc3\xc5\x91b\xddFVD\x1f\xe5\x15\xca\x92\xeffMhJJ\x95\xafx', b"\x85\xa1\xf9S\xe2%yh\x96\x9e|\xecg\xe1\x91\x8d\xfb\xa3\xa6\xcdc\x1e{\xfcD\xae\xc6\xe6\xc8\x14Qu\xd1\x80\xee#\\x80\xf7\xa8\xc66a-\xa6\xc57\xce\x17\xec\\xa3\xe7\x11\xe1\x167\xd5\xe4!\x8c\xa8f\xc5\xfd\x8dGY\xd6\xa4|\x8f\xbe\xd5\xdb\x17\xc5v'\x1dQ\x02\x00\x00"]

**Can anyone tell what is happened here, and how can i solve this?**

Comment: It seems that you received gzipped data. It can sometimes be caused by some AV/firewall that modifies the headers of the requests. Try to disable your antivirus. Alternatively, you could try to use the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library, which the official documentation recommends to use rather than urllib.

Comment: I found that it happened because the network it self, because i connect to another network and it worked fine.

also without changing the network, the Requests library worked perfect.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code is working now.

This issue happened because of the network it self, as after changing the network it worked fine, so maybe it happened because of some firewall configurations of the old network.

Also as [Thierry Lathuille](https://stackoverflow.com/users/550094/thierry-lathuille) suggest, without changing the network we can use the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library and it worked perfectly.

Thanks.